# Remove hostnames from a single line that follow a pattern in bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I need to cat a file and edit a **single line** with multiple domains names. Removing any domain name that has a set certain pattern of 4 letters ex: ozar.

This will be used in a **bash script** so the number of domain names can range, I will save this to a csv later on but right now returning a string is fine.

I tried multiple commands, loops, and if statements but sending the output to variable I can use further in the script proved to be another difficult task.

---

- Example file

  $ echo file.txt

  > ozarkzshared.com win.ad.win.edu win_fl.ozarkzsp.com ap.allk.org allk.org >ozarkz.com website.com

---

- What I attempted (that was close)

  domains_1=$(cat /tmp/file.txt | sed 's/ozar*//g')

  domains_2=$( cat /tmp/file.txt | printf '%s' "${string##*ozar}")

---

- Goal

  echo domain_x

  > win.ad.win.edu ap.allk.org allk.org website.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the domains are on a single line separated by spaces, this might work:

```
awk '/ozar/ {next} 1' RS=" " file.txt
```

This sets `RS`, your record separator, then skips any record that matches the keyword. If you wanted to be able to skip a substring provided in a shell variable, you could do something like this:

```
$ s=ozar
$ awk -v re="$s" '$0 ~ re {next} 1' RS=" " file.txt
```

Note that the `~` operator is comparing a regular expression, not precisely a substring. You could leverage the `index()` function if you really want to check a substring:

```
$ awk -v s="$s" 'index($0,s) {next} 1' RS=" " file.txt
```

---

Note that all of the above is `awk`, which isn't what you asked for. If you'd like to do this with bash alone, the following might be for you:

```
while read -r -a a; do
  for i in "${a[@]}"; do
    [[ "$i" = *"$s"* ]] || echo "$i"
  done
done < file.txt
```

This assigns each line of input to the array `$a[]`, then steps through that array testing for a substring match and printing if there is none. Text processing in bash is MUCH less efficient than in a more specialized tool like awk or sed. YMMV.

Comment: One last query @ghoti What would be the biggest difference/the impact between using "awk -v re="$s" '$0 ~ re {next} 1' RS=" " file.txt" or "$ awk -v s="$s" 'index($0,s) {next} 1' RS=" " file.txt" with the index() function?

Comment: FYI, you can use backquotes for in-line code formatting in these comments. I would expect that `index()` would evaluate faster than a regular expression, but the difference is probably negligible for small input files. Other than that.. not much difference for you, since none of the characters that make regular expressions special are allowed in domain names, aside from periods. Use whichever method brings you joy. :)

Answer (score 1):

you want to delete the words until a space delimiter

```
 $ sed 's/ozar[^ ]*//g' file

 win.ad.win.edu win_fl. ap.allk.org allk.org  website.com
```

Comment: @Juls `win_fl.` will not be what you want.

Comment: This solution will only delete full domain names that *begin* with the string "ozar". For the fun of it, try the following: `sed 's/ozar[^ ]*//g' <<<"wrozar.com ong.com"`